# No power to new GFCI

Tags: electrical, gfci

I'm trying to figure out why an exterior GFCI does not have power at the supply lines. Last week, my friend let an extension cord that was plugged into it fall into the water in the pool. She was certainly lucky that no one was in it.
There is an outlet directly opposite this inside the house, as well as an exterior light just above it, presumably on the same breaker.

Could something have happened to the wire that I cannot see inside the house?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

#### This is EXACTLY what GFCI is for

GFCI was created to handle exactly these types of situations. A **properly functioning** GFCI cuts off power when there is a ground fault, such as contact between power conductors and water, fast enough to prevent injury or death.

That being said, you should **always** be careful with any electric devices around water. Sometimes, as many questions on this site have shown, GFCI and other protective devices are not installed properly or fail for other reasons.

#### Does it reset?

Every GFCI has Test & Reset buttons. Does it reset? If it doesn't reset then either it still thinks there is a fault, or it is damaged.

#### Check the wiring and look for ANOTHER GFCI

If the GFCI is the only one on the circuit, then every receptacle (except the one that is together with the GFCI) is either *before* or *after* the GFCI. Every receptacle *after* the GFCI has the same protection as the GFCI receptacle itself, but that means a ground fault on any of those receptacles (or any equipment attached to them) will prevent the GFCI from being reset.

So check any receptacles that are on the same circuit. Unplug *everything* plugged into them, even if you think they have nothing to do with the problem, and try to reset the GFCI again.

Also look for any *additional* GFCI units. Sometimes there is more than one on a circuit, even though that is not necessary if wired correctly. The circuit breaker in the panel may also have GFCI built in to it, which protects the entire circuit. **When a fault occurs**, any combination of GFCIs in the circuit between the panel and the location of the fault may trip - with no guarantee of sequence. You could have a breaker plus two receptacle GFCIs and have the breaker plus one receptacle trip...any combination is possible.

#### Other damage?

With "traditional" short circuits, so much current can flow so fast that wire connections, switches, etc. can burn up or weld together before the circuit breaker trips. That should *not* be the case with a GFCI ground fault trip, but anything is possible. So if you rule out additional GFCIs and other ground faults then you need to check every receptacle and wire connection in the circuit to look for burn damage, faulty back stab connections or other problems.

Comment: The gfci will not reset. I've reset all of the others on the same floor level and checked every receptacle with a tester without issue. I will try the ground fault issue and disconnect everything on the suspected breaker line. Checking each receptacle and switch will follow if this doesn't work. I'll follow up after I get to it tomorrow...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere between the breaker and that receptacle is another receptacle or lamp.  Possibly more than one.

When they dropped the cord into the pool, they caused something to **break**.  Either a) the breake tripped due to flowing hundreds of amps of current, b) high current flow (perhaps only 10 amps) burned out a splice connection at a receptacle or switch, typically a backstab type connection, or c) there is already a GFCI somewhere along the circuit and *that* properly tripped.

So you need to search that circuit and look for any other receptacles or hardwired devices which have lost power.  While you're looking, also look for any GFCI receptacles or deadfronts, including at the breaker.

And-- when you find that location, if it's indoors, **put the GFCI receptacle there *instead***.  GFCI's are able to protect other loads besides the two sockets, and they are commonly used to protect the rest of the downline circuit.  Putting the GFCI in an indoor location will greatly extend its service life, while it still protects the outdoor receptacle that it feeds.  Fair chance a highly competent electrician or handyman *already did exactly that thing*.  That's why it's worth checking for.

Comment: That's great advice as well. I'll update you both when it's resolved.

Comment: Well...no luck today. I tried unplugging everything on the possible circuit to reset the gfci....no luck.                   I removed and inspected every outlet, switch and the outdoor lighting boxes and did not find any obvious damage.    There is one other gfci possibly on its same circuit but it appears fine and does reset. What are your thoughts?  I'm about to have to concede and refer them to the experts.